# How to load static files from separate S3 bucket when hosting site on Elastic Beanstalk Aws React Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Setup: React+Django hosted on Elastic Beanstalk. Static files hosted on separate S3 Bucket.

I'm trying to load an image using `src="/static/images/logo.png"`.

In development it works perfectly, but in production it sends a request to `XXX.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/images/logo.png` while it should be requesting `Bucket.amazonaws.com/static/images/logo.png`.

Meanwhile the user uploaded media is working perfectly for both POST and GET requests, images are stored and fetched from the Bucket `/media/` path.
I want to avoid conditionally coding the absolute url path depending on the environment.

I have a django `production_settings.py` file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '****************'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = '****************' 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '****************'


AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME



STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

`custom_storages.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION


class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `STATIC_URL` set incorrectly. It refers to your web app project path instead of S3 bucket URL. You can try using this below:

```
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

Comment: I think this would help for loading static files in to index.html using {% load_static %}, but I don't believe its possible to do the same in reacts .JS files. Setting the STATIC_URL has no effect on the domain the image url is routed to `src="/static/images/logo.png"`

Answer (score -1):

You have already extended [S3Boto3Storage](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/1.9.1/storages/backends/s3boto3.py#L201) and you could see there is multiple parameters,  you could set additional env key for static storage class:

```
class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
    custom_domain = setting('AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN_STATIC')
```

Comment: I included `custom_domain = settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` and it does not seem to work.

Comment: what do you mean you included custom_domain = settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

Comment: I followed your advice but used settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN as per the documentation and variables at hand.

Comment: no, as i said you have to introduce **new** variable for your other bucket and bundle it to another domain

Comment: as AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN uses AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME from first bucket you have to add additional variables for another bucket

Comment: But the static files Bucket is the AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN? Is there another way to explain this or an example you can provide?